# compare two columns in data frame, then produce 1 or 0 if they are equal or not

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I wanted to add a column that would tell me if two of my results were the same so I could calculate a % of true/1 or false/0

```
def same(closests):
    if 'ConvenienceStoreClosest' >= 'ConvenienceStoreClosestOSRM':
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

This is what I tried

df_all['same'] = df_all['ConvenienceStoreClosest'].apply(same)

[specific section from df_all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aFav.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use a loop/apply when you can use vectorial code.

In your case a simple way would be:

```
df_all['same'] = (df_all['ConvenienceStoreClosest']
                  .eq(df['ConvenienceStoreClosestOSRM'])
                  .astype(int)
                  )
```